# Need to Set_Formula on Insert_Row from IFTTT

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Novice Google Apps Scripter here,

I have an IFTTT applet which adds a row to this spreadsheet via email: [Data Test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJKiDNPUWMMUbLLb-UDA6iRA2PBnlMHDsEB9vELe0Rk/edit?usp=sharing)

I seem to have the formulas set up correctly, but when a new row is added, the formulas obviously do not auto-populate into that new row. When a row is inserted, in which the corresponding cells in Columns A and B are not blank, I'd like set certain formulas in that row.

The script I have so far (see below) does give me the formulas I want, but only in Row1. 
I'd like the script to set those same formulas into corresponding cells of any new row that is inserted.

For example, IFTTT.com automation will populate cells A6 and B6 with text (i.e., next blank row in linked spreadsheet) -- I need all of the formulas currently entered to then apply to B6 (as opposed to B2)

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var cell = sheet.getRange("C1");
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B2,SEARCH("details",$B2)+7,SEARCH(",",$B2)-SEARCH("details",$B2)-7),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  var cell = sheet.getRange("D1");
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B2,FIND("$",B2),LEN(B2))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100)),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  var cell = sheet.getRange("E1");
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B2,SEARCH("exceed",$B2)+7,SEARCH("%",$B2)-SEARCH("exceed",$B2)-6),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  var cell = sheet.getRange("F1");
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B2,SEARCH("due",$B2)+3,SEARCH(";",$B2)-SEARCH("due",$B2)-3),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  var cell = sheet.getRange("G1");
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B2,SEARCH("held on",$B2)+7,SEARCH(". Lottery",$B2)-SEARCH("held on",$B2)-7),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  var cell = sheet.getRange("H1");
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B2,SEARCH("posted by",$B2)+9,SEARCH(". ",$B2)-SEARCH("",$B2)-167),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');

}
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
function onOpen() {
  var items = [
    {name: 'Add Row', functionName: 'addrow'},
  ];
    ss.addMenu('Add Row', items);
    }
      
function addrow() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var result = ui.prompt(
      'Enter number of Row',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

    // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var rownum = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
  sheet.insertRowAfter(rownum);
  var cell = sheet.getRange("C" + rownum);
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + rownum +',SEARCH("details",$B' + rownum +')+7,SEARCH(",",$B' + rownum +')-SEARCH("details",$B' + rownum +')-7),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  var cell = sheet.getRange("D" + rownum);
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B' + rownum +',FIND("$",B' + rownum +'),LEN(B' + rownum +'))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100)),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  var cell = sheet.getRange("E" + rownum);
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + rownum +',SEARCH("exceed",$B' + rownum +')+7,SEARCH("%",$B' + rownum +')-SEARCH("exceed",$B' + rownum +')-6),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  var cell = sheet.getRange("F" + rownum);
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + rownum +',SEARCH("due",$B' + rownum +')+3,SEARCH(";",$B' + rownum +')-SEARCH("due",$B' + rownum +')-3),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  var cell = sheet.getRange("G" + rownum);
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + rownum +',SEARCH("held on",$B' + rownum +')+7,SEARCH(". Lottery",$B' + rownum +')-SEARCH("held on",$B' + rownum +')-7),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  var cell = sheet.getRange("H" + rownum);
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + rownum +',SEARCH("posted by",$B' + rownum +')+9,SEARCH(". ",$B' + rownum +')-SEARCH("",$B' + rownum +')-167),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".

  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.

  }
}
```

Comment: copying and pasting your answer, or adding it to my existing code?

Comment: copy / paste and then use the new menu function

Comment: you're going over my head here. what new menu function?

Comment: after you paste the script in reload the spreadsheet and you will see a new menu function next to "help" called "add Row"

Comment: Ok, got it but this isn't quite what I'm looking for. Let me try to explain. I do not need to add rows -- they are being added for me automatically. What I need is for the set of formulas to be applied to the cell in Column B corresponding to the new row that's been created.

Comment: For example, IFTTT.com automation will populate cells A6 and B6 with text (i.e., next blank row in linked spreadsheet) -- I need all of the formulas currently entered to then apply to B6. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well that button actually does set the formulas as well. it is just you having to press the button and enter the row. But if you want it automated, I am just not sure how you would know "when" to activate the script.

Comment: The button applied formulas referencing B2, not B6.

Comment: I edited the above code to have the formulas reference the new row

Comment: Ok good. That works for now. But is there a way to automatically detect that a row has been added, and use that as a trigger for adding the formulas which reference that row?

Comment: This may be a good for a new post and im not sure I know how to do this but would like to see if it can be done. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I've done in the past.  I was surprised to learn that there was a setFormula command because I didn't use it in this situation and the below technique is working fine.

```
for(var i = 0;i < rowA[0].length; i++)
  {
    var initial_value = rowA[0][i];
    //rowA[0][i] = '=ArrayFormula(IF(Row($B:$B)=1,"' + initial_value + '",IF(LEN($B:$B),IF(REGEXMATCH($C:$C,"(?i)(' + initial_value + ')"),$D:$D,""),)))';
    rowA[0][i] = '=ArrayFormula(IF(Row(' + sr  + ')=1,"' + initial_value + '",IF(LEN(' + sr  + '),IF(REGEXMATCH(' + sr  + ',"(?i)(' + initial_value + ')"),' + vr  + ',""),)))';
  }
  rowrng.setValues(rowA);
```

It's a little different from what your doing in that I'm setting all of the array values before running the setValues command. But this has been working for months.